# RPM Build - get user from installation machine

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am creating a RPM spec file to install a custom application, and I would like to install this application with specific **user:group**, the thing is that the user will follow a pattern (such as: **usr##**, where **##** could be any number from **00** to **99**), and each installation machine will have a different user which matches that pattern.

I tried to create a variable in the spec file, using %define macro, to get the user from OS and use it to assign the defattr:

```
%define _user %(sed -n -r 's/(usr[0-9]{2}).*/\\1/p' /etc/passwd)

%files
%defattr(755,%{_user},group)
```

But the macro is being expanded in build time, so it is getting the user from my building machine, and not from the installation machine (a separate machine). I also tried to put it into both %pre and %post sections and neither work.

Does anyone know how can I get the user from installation machine? Thanks!

Comment: No you cannot do this. Why are you want to change the user in first place?

Comment: @msuchy I need to change it to meet the specification, but if it is not possible with rpm, then I will have to do it after installation. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: As noted, this isn't how RPMs work. See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:UsersAndGroups for more suggestions on what you might want to try instead.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can try to use the postinstall section. The post section executes the commands as a script during rpm installation. No macros in this section!

```
%post
user=$(sed -n -r 's/(usr[0-9]{2}).*/\1/p' /etc/passwd)
chown -R ${user} <path>
```